# Compile a C file whose filename contains spaces

Tags: r, c

I want to compile a C file to use the generated dynamic library in R.
When the filename of the C file doesn't contain any space, no problem; when it does contain at least one, I get errors. I tried with escape characters (`\"`, `\'`) and with `shQuote` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Below a reproducible example.

Essai 1.c:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#define R_NO_REMAP  /* To avoid the 'Rf_' prefixes to functions' names etc.*/ /* See: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fee68fa94b6586bd2e257c0993cd79c4258a0876/src/include/Rinternals.h#L1505 */

SEXP add(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
    SEXP result = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
    REAL(result)[0] = asReal(a) + asReal(b);
    /* Modify the global (or the variable from the R global environment) variable 'N.Nodes' */
    SEXP N_Nodes = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1));
    INTEGER(N_Nodes)[0] = asInteger(findVar(install("N.Nodes"), R_GlobalEnv));
    int N_Nodes_Copy;
    N_Nodes_Copy = asInteger(findVar(install("N.Nodes"), R_GlobalEnv));
    INTEGER(N_Nodes)[0] = asInteger(N_Nodes) + 2;
    /*int N_Nodes = asInteger(findVar(install("N.Nodes"), R_GlobalEnv));
    N_Nodes = N_Nodes + 2;*/
    defineVar(install("N.Nodes"), N_Nodes, R_GlobalEnv);
    printf("N_Nodes_Copy = %d\n", N_Nodes_Copy);
    
    UNPROTECT(2);

    return result;
}
```

Essai 1.R:

```
N.Nodes <- 145
system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', 'Essai 1.c'))
dyn.load("Essai 1.dll")

add <- function(x, y){
    return(.Call("add", as.double(x), as.double(y)))
}
N.Nodes
add(1, pi)
N.Nodes

dyn.unload("Essai 1.dll")
```

Comment: In C, use [`Rprintf`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Printing), not `printf`.

Comment: Using `shQuote` around your parameters in `system2` would work in principle. But unfortunately in this particular case *this does not work* because R configures its builds via Makefiles, and GNU make does not handle spaces in filenames. Yes, this is a bug in GNU make but unfortunately it will never be fixed. — I’m a huge proponent of using spaces in filenames (they’re valid: they should work; deal with it). But in this particular case the only proper solution is to remove the spaces.

Comment: Also, be aware that your `dyn.load` code is non-portable: only Windows uses the `.dll` file extension. Use `.Platform$dynlib.ext` to find the correct file extension: `libname = function (name) paste0(name, .Platform$dynlib.ext)`

Comment: Many thanks for your explanations, @Konrad Rudolph. Yes, I already replaced the spaces by underscores but wanted to know the reason why it wasn't working. I fully agree with you: I’m also a huge proponent of using spaces in filenames.
Yes, indeed, good point with `.dll`, I amended that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
Write a function to make a copy of the filename with spaces to a unique filename, compile this temp file, then rename the DLL.

```r
make_shlib_with_spaces <- function(x) {
  # make unique name, I hope
  y <- gsub(" ", "_==_", x)
  if(file.exists(y))
    unlink(y)
  # these are the shared objects names
  target_dll <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x), .Platform$dynlib.ext)
  compiled_dll <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(y), .Platform$dynlib.ext)
  # compile the temp source
  file.copy(x, y)
  system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', y))
  # if the wanted, target shared object exists, delete it
  if(file.exists(target_dll))
    unlink(target_dll)
  # target shared object
  file.rename(compiled_dll, target_dll)
  # clean up after yourself
  delete <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = tools::file_path_sans_ext(y))
  unlink(delete)
  # return the shared object's name
  target_dll
}

add <- function(x, y){
  return(.Call("add", as.double(x), as.double(y)))
}

N.Nodes <- 145

dll <- make_shlib_with_spaces("Essai 1.c")
dyn.load(dll)

N.Nodes
#> [1] 145
add(1, pi)
#> N_Nodes_Copy = 145
#> [1] 4.141593
N.Nodes
#> [1] 147

dyn.unload(dll)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>